# Change Default Search list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, search

Hi the default Magento search uses /catalog/product/list.phtml

How can I create a custom version of this file "list_search.phtml" and tell the search to use this file instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via layout.

In your theme folder create or edit a layout/local.xml file, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>your/custom/list_search.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    <!-- Only for advanced search -->
    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>your/custom/list_search.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result>
</layout>
```